# How to add the Data to the 'categoryB' and 'categoryC' in Echart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, echarts

I have some problem with the Echart.js. Actually its not a big problem, i just want to add the data to the 'categoryB' and 'categoryC'. But i dont know how to do. I will provide you the image, code and Github to this chart.

[The chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaxtA.jpg)

github to this chart: https://github.com/suplex2825/chart-

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
       <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="dist2/echarts-gl.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="dist3/ecStat.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/extension/dataTool.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="map/js/china.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="map/js/world.js"></script>
<!--       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=ZUONbpqGBsYGXNIYHicvbAbM"></script>-->
       <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/extension/bmap.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="test/lib/simplex.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
var dom = document.getElementById("container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
var app = {};
option = null;

var data = [
    {            name: 'e',
            value: [
                0,
                '2016/12/18 00:00:00',
                '2016/12/18 00:30:05',
                5
            ],
            itemStyle: {
                normal: {
                    color: 'blue'
                }
            }},    {            name: 'e',
            value: [
                0,
                '2016/12/18 01:00:00',
                '2016/12/18 01:30:05',
                '123wewe'
            ],
            itemStyle: {
                normal: {
                    color: 'blue'
                }
            }}
    ];
var dataCount = 10;
var startTime = +new Date();
var categories = ['categoryA', 'categoryB', 'categoryC'];
var types = [
    {name: 'JS Heap', color: '#7b9ce1'},
    {name: 'Documents', color: '#bd6d6c'},
    {name: 'Nodes', color: '#75d874'},
    {name: 'Listeners', color: '#e0bc78'},
    {name: 'GPU Memory', color: '#dc77dc'},
    {name: 'GPU', color: '#72b362'}
];
var anchor = [
    {name:'2016/12/18 00:00:00', value:['2016/12/18 00:00:00', 0]},
    {name:'2016/12/19 00:00:00', value:['2016/12/19 00:00:00', 0]}
    ];
// Generate mock data
/*echarts.util.each(categories, function (category, index) {
    var baseTime = startTime;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
        var typeItem = types[Math.round(Math.random() * (types.length - 1))];
        var duration = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
        data.push({
            name: typeItem.name,
            value: [
                index,
                baseTime,
                baseTime += duration,
                duration
            ],
            itemStyle: {
                normal: {
                    color: typeItem.color
                }
            }
        });
        baseTime += Math.round(Math.random() * 2000);
    }
});*/
console.log(data);
function renderItem(params, api) {
    console.log(api);
    var categoryIndex = api.value(0);
    var start = api.coord([api.value(1), categoryIndex]);
    var end = api.coord([api.value(2), categoryIndex]);
    var height = api.size([0, 1])[1] * 0.6;

    return {
        type: 'rect',
        shape: echarts.graphic.clipRectByRect({
            x: start[0],
            y: start[1] - height / 2,
            width: end[0] - start[0],
            height: height
        }, {
            x: params.coordSys.x,
            y: params.coordSys.y,
            width: params.coordSys.width,
            height: params.coordSys.height
        }),
        style: api.style()
    };
}


option = {
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function (params) {
            return params.marker + params.name + ': ' + params.value[3] + ' ms';
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Profile',
        left: 'center'
    },
    legend: {
        data: ['bar', 'error']
    },
    dataZoom: [{
        type: 'slider',
        filterMode: 'weakFilter',
        showDataShadow: false,
        top: 400,
        height: 10,
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        backgroundColor: '#e2e2e2',
        handleIcon: 'M10.7,11.9H9.3c-4.9,0.3-8.8,4.4-8.8,9.4c0,5,3.9,9.1,8.8,9.4h1.3c4.9-0.3,8.8-4.4,8.8-9.4C19.5,16.3,15.6,12.2,10.7,11.9z M13.3,24.4H6.7v-1.2h6.6z M13.3,22H6.7v-1.2h6.6z M13.3,19.6H6.7v-1.2h6.6z', // jshint ignore:line
        handleSize: 20,
        handleStyle: {
            shadowBlur: 6,
            shadowOffsetX: 1,
            shadowOffsetY: 2,
            shadowColor: '#aaa'
        },
        labelFormatter: ''
    }, {
        type: 'inside',
        filterMode: 'weakFilter'
    }],
    grid: {
        height:300
    },
    xAxis: {
        type:'time',
        //min: startTime,
        scale: true,
        //axisLabel: {
        //    formatter: function (val) {
       //         return Math.max(0, val - startTime) + ' ms';
       //     }
       // }
    },
    yAxis: {
        data: categories
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'custom',
        renderItem: renderItem,
        itemStyle: {
            normal: {
                opacity: 0.8
            }
        },
        encode: {
            x: [1, 2],
            y: 0
        },
        data: data
    },{
        name:'.anchor',
        type:'line', 
        showSymbol:false, 
        data:anchor,
        itemStyle:{normal:{opacity:0}},
        lineStyle:{normal:{opacity:0}}
    }]
};
;
myChart.on('click',function(p){
    console.log('click');
    console.log(p)
});
if (option && typeof option === "object") {
    myChart.setOption(option, true);
}
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope you guys can help me out and thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Your renderItem method needs to return multiple children. Right now, you're just returning one child. You can actually select which children you want to show by including that in your return.

So to summarize, you need to do something like this:

```
    return {
        type: 'group',
        children: [
            {
            type: 'rect',
            ignore: api.value(0) !== 'Category B' && api.value(0) !== 'Category C',
            shape: echarts.graphic.clipRectByRect({
                x: start[0],
                y: start[1] - height / 2,
                width: end[0] - start[0],
                height: height
            }, 
            {
                x: params.coordSys.x,
                y: params.coordSys.y,
                width: params.coordSys.width,
                height: params.coordSys.height
            }),
            style: api.style(),
        },
        {
        type : 'rect',
        ignore : api.value(0) !== 'Category A' && api.value(0) !== 'Category C',
        shape : echarts.graphic.clipRectByRect({
            x: start[0],
            y: start[1] - height / 2,
            width: end[0] - start[0],
            height: height
        }, 
        {
            x: params.coordSys.x,
            y: params.coordSys.y,
            width: params.coordSys.width,
            height: params.coordSys.height
        }),
        style: api.style(),
        }]
    };
```

Hope this helps!